# How to override new Date() on Protractor tests

Tags: javascript, date, protractor, overriding

I've an app that changes it's behaviour with the date. On my mock tests I need to override the `new Date()` function to test all the scenarios. Does anyone know how to override it?

I already tried to use the executeScript to change the return value but it doesn't work.

`browser.driver.executeScript('' +
   'Date = function(){return new Date(2012, 0, 20)};'
);`

Answer (score 0):

The replacement function depends on the original Date that's been replaced, so keep a reference to it in a closure, e.g.:

```js
var Date = (function() {
  var OldDate = Date;
  return function (){
    return new OldDate(2012,0,20);
  }
}());

alert(new Date());
```