# Override Date constructor executing script

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate some tests using cucumber js, and one is dependent of a function calling new Date().

I've tried to executeScript and override the Date like this.

```
    const driver = (this.driver as ThenableWebDriver); 
    await driver.get(`http://localhost:5000/`);
    await driver.executeScript(`
        var d = new Date(2012,0,20);
        Date = function(){return d;}
    `);
```

if i call a executeScript function again with

```
await driver.executeScript(`
        alert(new Date()) // returns the date i set
    `);
```

the new Date returns correctly.
But when i simulate a click, and that onClick does a new Date(), it gets the local Date and not the date i set.

Any tip?
Thanks in advance

[EDIT] saw this here: [How to override new Date() on Protractor tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432070/how-to-override-new-date-on-protractor-tests)

```
var Date = (function() {
 var OldDate = Date;
 return function (){
 return new OldDate(2012,0,20);
 } 
}());
```

But still no luck. where does the executeScript run?

Comment: i coded the onclick callback, i call new Date() explicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override the constructor `Date`:

```js
await driver.executeScript(`
  var Date = function() {                         // new constructor
    return new window.Date.prototype.constructor(2013, 6, 14);
  }
  Date.prototype = window.Date.prototype;         // inherit the methods from Date
  Date.now = Date;                                // override Date.now()
  Date.UTC = Date.prototype.constructor.UTC;      // copy Date.UTC(...)
  Date.parse = Date.prototype.constructor.parse;  // copy Date.parse(...)
  window.Date = Date;                             // override Date
`);
```